# Android Studio fails to find SDK

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio and unzipped the file. When I run it, it loads but then says "Please provide path to Android SDK". I have tried loads of different file paths but nothing happens. Am I missing a file that I need to download or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Update your PATH to point to the Android SDK Platform-tools directory. I didn't provide how you can do that because it depends on the OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 0.8.14 update the SDK is not provided with in the zip when you download Android Studio. For some reason the SDK now has to be in a different folder.

Download the SDK seperately here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Install it somewhere (I have it in C:/sdk). On the Android studio welcome screen goto Configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure and provide the path to the SDK in the first field.

I assumed you use windows, but this should be very similar on other systems.